# Nativescript audio issue

Tags: android, nativescript

Hello guys Im having issue with [NS audio](https://github.com/nstudio/nativescript-audio) plugin:

Code for my js file

```
const audio = require('nativescript-audio');
const player = new audio.TNSPlayer();

function play(){
 const playerOptions = {
        audioFile: url,  // url is variable where file is located
        loop: false,
        completeCallback() {
             console.log("playback completed");
        },
        errorCallback(errorObject) {
             console.log("Error");
        },
        infoCallback(args) {

        },
    }

    if (player.isAudioPlaying()) {
        player.dispose();
            playIt(playerOptions);
        }
    } else {
        playIt(playerOptions);
    }
}


function playIt(playerOptions){
player.playFromUrl(playerOptions)
        .then((res) => {

    }).catch(() => {

    });
}
```

and my xml:

```
<Button text="play" tap="play"></Button>
```

So the issue is happening when I try to send sms on my emulator like this
https://ibb.co/dsZLkx

while Im on that page, or if Im on that page and I plug in USB to my real phone.. My app crashes and it displays following message:
[Error message](https://ibb.co/mUj9TH)

I think there is a conflict when some other sound is head at the same time on device, and it is not properly handled in a plugin,
but Im weak with android, so could someone help me or provide some info Ill try to fix it myself.

[Link to github issue I created](https://github.com/nstudio/nativescript-audio/issues/96)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is fixed by developers of plugin,
just update plugin to latest version..

Here is also a link to issue:

[Github Link](https://github.com/nstudio/nativescript-audio/issues/96)